# How do I update a variable by grabbing text from a textbox in tkinter using the enter key?

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter and trying to create a chat program. I have it set to open a new window that prompts you to enter the IP of the user you wish to connect to. When you press enter it is supposed to update a variable to that IP address for later use. The problem is the variable is not updating, instead, it is keeping its initial value. I am using the `.get()` function to grab text from the textbox. When I print the `.get()` function it works but setting the variable using `.get()` does not work. Send is still printing 1. Any ideas?

```
other_address = 1

def join():
    newWindow = Toplevel(master) 

newWindow.title("IP") 

newWindow.geometry("300x50") 

directions = Label(newWindow, text="Enter the IP Address of the user you would like to join")
directions.pack()

enter_hostname = Entry(newWindow)
enter_hostname.pack()
newWindow.bind("<Return>", lambda x: other_address == enter_hostname.get())
newWindow.bind("<Return>", lambda x: print(enter_hostname.get()))

def send():
    print (other_address)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the SyntaxError given in the comments:
The issue here is that a lambda expression creates a 'scope' which means that when it ends any variables it has created are automatically destroyed. The solution to this is to create a proper function which gets `other_address` into its global scope so that it can edit it properly like so:

```
def set_address(x):
    global other_address
    other_address = enter_hostname.get()
```

Then the binding can be:

```
newWindow.bind("<Return>", set_address)
```

Where you just pass the set_address function to it instead of a lambda expression

Comment: Okay the only issue I am having with that is a nameError. It says enter_hostname is not defined. Is there any way I can make that global when I define it?

Comment: @whearn17 Because you are running an operation on enter_hostname rather than assigning it it doesn't need to be global. The issue is that you are initialising the function before the variable enter_hostname so you need to place that function definition in between the `enter_hostname.pack()` and `newWindow...` lines instead of further up

Answer (score 0):

A double equals operator `==` does not create a variable in python, instead it is what is called an equality operator, so it checks whether they are equal and returns True or False. To set a variable in python you instead need to use a single equals, `=` so that line would become:
`newWindow.bind("<Return>", lambda x: other_address = enter_hostname.get())`

Comment: I keep getting this: SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

Comment: @whearn17 the issue here is that a lambda expression is not allowed to hold an assignment because it should be one line and is its own 'scope' so any variable assignment it makes is not going to mean anything. If you are only going to do this once you could consider setting `other_address` to 0 at the start and then doing `other_address += enter_hostname.get()` in the lambda function, if this will be called multiple times in one run, see my next answer for a more comprehensive solution